# Correlated subquery issue in Hive / Spark SQL to compare aggregates

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table of about a billion game interactions where each record describes attributes of a gamer on a particular day (gamer ID, date on which the game was played, attribute 1, [attribute 2, ...])

```
+---------+
| TABLE_1 |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|gmr_id | played_dt | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
|1      | 2017-01-01| 1     | 2     | txt   |
|1      | 2017-01-02| 3     | 2     | txt   |
|2      | 2017-01-02| 1     | 2     | txt   |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have another table with millions of records where the gamers moves are recorded for each game played:

```
+---------+
| TABLE_2 |
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|gmr_id | played_dt | finish  | attacks | deaths  |
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
|1      | 2017-01-01| 10      | 1       | 9       |
|1      | 2017-01-03| 12      | 10      | 2       |
|2      | 2017-01-02| 1       | 0       | 0       |
|4      | 2017-01-03| 1       | 0       | 1       |
|1      | 2017-01-04| 3       | 1       | 2       |
+-------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

For every record in TABLE_1 -- specifically for every gmr_id and played_dt, I am trying to compare sums of moves in next two days of played_dt with previous five days (1 if true, else 0) and join to TABLE_1 based on gmr_id and played_dt:
i.e.

1. Sum of finishes, attacks and deaths for the gmr_id from played_dt to two days after, i.e. SUM(finishes), SUM(attacks) etc. `BETWEEN played_dt AND DATE_ADD(played_dt, 2)`
2. Sum of finishes, attacks and deaths for the gmr_id from five days before to one day before played_dt, i.e SUM(finishes), SUM(attacks) etc. `BETWEEN DATE_SUB(played_dt, 5) AND DATE_SUB(played_dt, 1)`
3. Compare and set flags i.e. get a row that looks like: gmr_id, played_dt, future_finish_gt_past_finish (1 if finish in days after played_dt greater than days before else 0), future_attacks_gt_past_attacks (1 if attacks in days after played_dt are greater than days before else 0), etc.

Join the row: `gmr_id, played_dt, finish_f, attack_f`
with TABLE_1 row: `gmr_id, played_dt, attr1, attr2, attr3`
on `gmr_id, played_dt`

I have tried writing correlated sub-query but to no-avail:

```
SELECT
  t1.gmr_id,
  t1.played_dt,    
  (SELECT
    t2.gmr_id,
    SUM(t2.finish) `future_finish`,
    SUM(t2.attacks) `future_attacks`
  FROM TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t2.played_dt BETWEEN played_dt AND DATE_ADD(played_dt, 2)
  GROUP BY t2.gmr_id), 
  (SELECT
    t2.gmr_id,
    SUM(t2.finish) `past_finish`,
    SUM(t2.attacks) `past_attacks`
  FROM TABLE_2 t2 WHERE t2.played_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(played_dt, 5) AND DATE_SUB(played_dt, 1)
  GROUP BY t2.gmr_id),

CASE WHEN future_finish > past_finish THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `finish_f`,

CASE WHEN future_attacks > past_attacks THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `attack_f`

FROM
  TABLE_1 t1;
```

The expected output looks like this:

```
+---------+
| TABLE_1 |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|gmr_id | played_dt | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | finish_f  | attack_f  |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|1      | 2017-01-01| 1     | 2     | txt   |     1     |     0     |
|1      | 2017-01-02| 3     | 2     | txt   |     1     |     1     |
|2      | 2017-01-02| 1     | 2     | txt   |     0     |     1     |
+-------+-----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

I am using Hive 1.2 (or could use Spark 1.5) to do this, but so far I have been unable to do so. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: A data example **including the required results** would be much more effective than textual explanations

Comment: Take a look at Spark window functions: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html In your case, the window will be variable because you are looking at `DATE_ADD(played_dt, 2)` and `DATE_SUB(played_dt, 5)` but you know it has a limit of at most 2 and 5 rows in the respective directions. You can therefore compute all possible windows into separate columns and then select the appropriate one based on the date using a `case` statement.

Comment: Rahul, nothing here makes sense - not the data model, not the data sample and not the query (logically and technically).

Comment: @Sim Thank you for the reference.